# Error: Failed to start application: Call to undefined function Joomla\CMS\Language\simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml, joomla, simplexml

I am getting the error mentioned in the question, I am using:

- Linux Mint 18
- LAMP
- Joomla3.5
- solr-7

I have already installed the required libraries here are the screenshots:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UgD0.png)

I reinstalled the module using the `synaptic manager` and restarted `apache` but still the error persists. 
Please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: You should include the code where you are getting the error as well.

Comment: The forum topic at https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=960771 recommends to install and activate the XML extension - is it loaded in your case?

Comment: I had the same problem. I think the issue is that php is trying to invoke the function simplexml_load_file() inside the class Joomla\CMS\Language wich doesn't exist (it's a builtin php function). I just restarted the server and it was solved.

Comment: This totally saved my day: after lot of time & troubleshooting rebooting the server made the trick, unbelievable.